# Microphone high pitched until default format quality is changed

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone

**Microphone:** `Logitech Webcam C500`

Whenever my computer starts up or wakes up from sleep mode and I go to use my microphone anything I say will be in a very high pitched form and sound as though I have turned into Alvin from the Chipmunks.

In order to fix the problem every time I come back from sleep mode and want to use the microphone I have had to perform the following steps.

Go into the properties of the microphone, hit the "Advanced" tab, and then change the default format to something else. As long as I change it to a different format, doesn't matter to which one, the pitch of the microphone goes back to normal and functions as expected.

Here is a little GIF showing the steps I described:

[image: example]

Unfortunately while this solves the problem temporary it is rather annoying to do every single time and as such I'd like to figure out the root cause for this.

Comment: Are you using the correct driver?

Comment: @root Yes, I am using the driver found on the manufactors website: http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/webcam-c500

Comment: I have the same problem. Sometimes my voice sounds like Chipmulk and I didn't even know it! Are you using a Logitech Webcam by any chance? I have this problem on 2 Logitech webcams (Pro 9000 and c905). I am running the official Logitech driver installed by Windows. It goes away if I toggle the mic input from webcam to laptop and back. Easier than going to Sound Settings. YMMV if you use a desktop with no built-in mic. I would love to know a solution that fixes it for good.

Comment: @someuser Yes it was a logitech webcam. This was back in 2016 and I have since upgraded to a standalone microphone but yes my issue is exactly what you are describing. I have no idea what causes it but I think the only solution so far is to just a different device unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

I think the issue is not necessarly with the changing the freq. The fix happens when you reload the sound driver in windows 10. Not sure how to setup the default audio device to use for the mic.

Comment: Can you go into specific detail how the author solve's their problem?

Comment: Yes, that is essentially what I am doing, however that does not fix the problem of WHY I need to do this for every time I go to my computer. Even with the new Windows 10 upgrade the problem is still there.